handle multiple date format in one output in datastage
I have multiple date format on my source column (YYYY/DD/MM, YYYY/MM/DD,YYYY-DD-MM,YYYY-MM-DD...) and need to load it in one output column
the source column is varchar and the output is timestamp
how can i do this on a transformer

How would you even decide between YYYY/DD/MM and YYYY/MM/DD for the first 12 days of a month? I suggest to restrict your input to one format. Somewhere in the source chain you have to constraint your input data to one format. If it comes from different sources, make the format equal before merging.

Determine the format within the transformer and use StringToTimestamp to re-format it to the timestamp format of your target.
In order to figure out the format you could use len (length) function or just check for substrings to check if "/" oder "-" separators are used etc.
